# remove scroll for iframe in thickBox plugin

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, thickbox

I am using thickbox http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

and I am using `body` css for all pages

```
body {
    width: 960px
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have two pages `master.php` and `sub.php`

### master.php

```
<a href="sub.php?keepThis=true&height=550&width=900" title="Test title" class="thickbox">Open</a>
```

### sub.php

I have some content init
and in this i have `css` `body` is applied here.

So, when i click on `Open`, the thickbox iframe is perfectly good.
But i dont need the scrolls both horizontal and vertically

By increasing the `width` in `<anchor>` element i have no scroll horizontall,
and now i want the `height` to be fixed with no scrolling for that `iframe` popup

I have tested some of the tweaks, but its not working out.

And i have added an image below. so that you can understand it better

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:hidden;` to your css code.

Comment: in `iframe` content page or the master page